# How to implement EAR-wide JAAS

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, jaas, geronimo

I'd like to implement JAAS across the whole of my EAR file containing multiple wars.

I have successfuly set it up on each war, but that means when the user is switching between wars (via hyperlinks between) they have to log-in again for each, even though each war is configured to use the same realm.

How can I create a single sign-on process for the whole of the EAR?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer! - single sign on across all apps in the same servlet context and for the same security realm. Its available with tomcat. I simply updated the config.xml as advised on the below url and it now only asks to sign in once.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/wasce/V2.1.0/en/valves.html#Valves-AddingtheSingleSignonValvetotheinitialvalvechain

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html#Single_Sign_On might be of use too.

Comment: Just to make it clear for others who may later visit this question: this valve is great for web-only applications (web, soap, rest), but not enough when you also have clients that want to talk to the application over rmi (or its vendor equivalent).

Answer (score 2):

This is usually container-specific.
For [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/), you can use `yourapp.ear/META-INF/jboss-app.xml` for this purpose. Here, you define a `security-domain` element that points to the respective login-policy. Excerpt from the DTD:

> <!--   The security-domain element
>   specifies the JNDI name of the
>   security   manager that implements the
>   EJBSecurityManager and RealmMapping
>   for   the domain. When specified at
>   the jboss level it specifies the
>   security   domain for all j2ee
>   components in the deployment unit.
>   One can override the global
>   security-domain at the container
>   level using the security-domain
>   element at the container-configuration
>   level.
>
> Used in: jboss-app
>   -->
>
> <!ELEMENT security-domain (#PCDATA)>

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, Yes I have done this with Geronimo (v2.1). but its still requesting a log-in on each module. Im guessing that's because it's a new session each time? I have all configuration set up in the geronimo-application.xml except the security constraints which are in the appropriate web.xml

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about Geronimo.